# Can't make InfiniteViewPager work

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I can't make Infinite View Pager of Antonyt work. https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager
Does anyone have any sample code? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you developing in eclipse?

Comment: ```InfiniteViewPager``` was created by the Android Studio, do you reconfig the project right in eclipse?

Comment: what do you mean by reconfig? i think i haven't tried that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have imported the two projects named `main` and `InfiniteViewPagerActivity`

in the `main` project:

- right click the `java` directory, and select `build path` menu, and click the `Use as Source folder`.
- right click the `main` project directory, and click `properties` menu, select left `Android` menu, and check the `Is Library` menu.
- right click the `main` project directory, and select `Android tools` menu,  and click `Add Android Support library` menu(ensure the `android-support-v4.jar` file in the `libs` directory)

in the `InfiniteViewPagerActivity`

- right click the `main` project directory, and click `properties` menu, select left `Android` menu, click `add`, add the `main` project.
- right click the `java` directory, and select `build path` menu, and click the `Use as Source folder`.

ok, run `InfiniteViewPagerActivity`.